# apply event to elements using .on

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax

`.on` not working on my page to apply click event to the elements loaded with ajax . `#myimageflow` is the container and i am loading images using ajax. when i am trying .on for click it is not working instead .live is working perfectly .

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    /*   Reading the data from XML file*/
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "photos.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {
            $(xml).find('item').each(function() {
                var path = $(this).attr('path');
                var width = $(this).attr('width');
                var height = $(this).attr('height');
                var id = $(this).attr('id');
                var alt = $(this).attr('alt');
                var longdesc = $(this).find('longdesc').text();
                var description = $(this).find('desc').text();
                $('#myImageFlow').append('<img src="' + path + '" id=' + id + '  height="' + height + '"  width="' + width + '" longdesc="' + longdesc + '" alt="' + alt + '"/>');
                imgArr[i] = description;
                imgFront[i] = longdesc;

                i = i + 1;

            });
        }
    });

    /* ===================================== */
    //$("#myImageFlow").show();
    $.getScript('js/iSlider.js');
    $.getScript('js/code.photoswipe.jquery-3.0.5.js');
});

/*front div called when front or back is called*/

$('#myImageFlow').on("click", 'img', function() {

    alert("image clicked");
});
```

Comment: For God's sake, format your code!

Comment: `$('body').on("click", '#myImageFlow img',  function()` try this

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using

Answer (score 1):

Put this part in the `ready` callback :

```
$('#myImageFlow').on("click", 'img',  function() {
   alert("image clicked");     
});
```

The `#myImageFlow` element must be found when you do this binding. As you put this code out of the `ready` callback, it's executed before the element is available.

Comment: Yup that will do the trick, or changing the selector to document level instead.

Comment: @PSR `live` works differently than `on` : the selector of the element on which the binding is done is evaluated again when the event occurs.

Answer (score 1):

solved by making it,

```
$(document).on('click', 'img', function() {
  alert('htmlcalled image Clicked Called='+clickEnabled);
         ......
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

`.live` is deprecated.If you are using older version of jQuery `.live()` will wotk for u. `.on` will not work

Comment: Why down vote.who gave me the downvote.What is the reason for that

Comment: i dont know with out knowing the reason why they are giving downvotw

Comment: Not my downvote, but don't take it so hard. Guess someone thought it's obvious the OP is familiar with `.on()` enough to include proper jQuery version..

Comment: ok ok sir.But when dow vote some thing it is good to leave a comment

Comment: Agree about comment but we can't force it. As for `.live()` it's removed only in version 1.9 see [here](http://api.jquery.com/live/). Any version below 1.9 (and above 1.3 of course) will still support it as backward compatibility.